# How to improve/simplify a query with a lot of subquerys?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I have a sql query that sum and counts some registers from my db, the problem is that I'm using a lot of subquerys and all of them have the same condition, I need to find a better solution because this is causing slowness in my system.

I tried to use a simple left join but mysql returned a single row and I want that counts and sum every register on the table dbgeneralesImportacion.

I have something like this:

```
SELECT  dbgeneralesImportacion.id,
        sapito.dbgeneralesImportacion.documentosCompletos AS 'documentosCompletos', 
        (SELECT COUNT(c.id) 
        FROM sapito.dbcontenedores c 
        WHERE c.operacion = dbgeneralesImportacion.id ) AS 'ContadorContenedores', 
        (SELECT SUM(IF(c.estatus = 1, 1, 0)) 
        FROM sapito.dbcontenedores c 
        WHERE c.operacion = dbgeneralesImportacion.id ) AS 'ContadorDespachos', 
        (SELECT SUM(IF(c.estatus = 2, 1, 0)) 
        FROM sapito.dbcontenedores c 
        WHERE c.operacion = dbgeneralesImportacion.id ) AS 'ContadorCompletado', 
        (SELECT SUM(IF(c.desconsolidacion = 1, 1, 0)) 
        FROM sapito.dbcontenedores c 
        WHERE c.operacion = dbgeneralesImportacion.id ) AS 'DesconsolidacionPuerto',
        (SELECT SUM(c.bultos) FROM sapito.dbcontenedores c WHERE c.operacion = dbgeneralesImportacion.id)  AS 'bultos'
FROM    dbgeneralesImportacion

And my idea was to do this but counts all register and return a single row:

SELECT  dbgeneralesImportacion.id AS 'id',
        COUNT(c.id) AS 'ContadorContenedores', 
        SUM(IF(c.estatus = 1, 1, 0))  AS 'ContadorDespachos', 
        SUM(IF(c.estatus = 2, 1, 0))  AS 'ContadorCompletado', 
        SUM(IF(c.desconsolidacion = 1, 1, 0))  AS 'DesconsolidacionPuerto',
        SUM(c.bultos)  AS 'bultos'
FROM    dbgeneralesImportacion
        LEFT JOIN dbcontenedores c ON c.operacion = dbgeneralesImportacion.id

Thank you everyone
```

Comment: If you are using MySQL 8.x you can use CTEs to reuse subqueries.

Comment: In my personal computer I use MYSQL 8 but the server has 5.7 version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a join a and group  by

```
     SELECT  a.id
         , a.documentosCompletos
         , COUNT(c.id) ContadorContenedores
         , SUM(IF(c.estatus = 1, 1, 0)) ContadorDespachos
         , SUM(IF(c.estatus = 2, 1, 0)) ContadorCompletado
         , SUM(IF(c.desconsolidacion = 1, 1, 0)) DesconsolidacionPuerto
         ,  SUM(c.bultos) bultos

     FROM    dbgeneralesImportacion a
     INNER JOIN sapito.dbcontenedores c ON c.operacion = a.id
     GRUP BY a.id, a.documentosCompletos
```

Comment: It worked!! thank you very much, JoshGivens's answer also works, sad that I only can choose one answer

Comment: @AlejandroCoronadoRubio  ..  this is SO  ..   choose the better  or if are similar coose the first  ..

Answer (score 1):

Not positive, but couldn't you do something like this

```
SELECT  dbgeneralesImportacion.id,
sapito.dbgeneralesImportacion.documentosCompletos AS 'documentosCompletos', 
COUNT(c.id)  AS 'ContadorContenedores', 
SUM(IF(c.estatus = 1, 1, 0)) AS 'ContadorDespachos', 
SUM(IF(c.estatus = 2, 1, 0)) AS 'ContadorCompletado', 
SUM(IF(c.desconsolidacion = 1, 1, 0)) AS 'DesconsolidacionPuerto',
SUM(c.bultos) AS 'bultos'

FROM    dbgeneralesImportacion, sapito.dbcontenedores c

WHERE c.operacion = dbgeneralesImportacion.id 
GROUP BY dbgeneralesImportacion.id
```

Comment: It worked very good!!, thank yout very much!!! but I just can choose one answer :(

Comment: It's all good, the other answer was slightly better than mine since it utilized proper joins instead of just linking them in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `GROUP BY`, but you can also simplify the query:

```
SELECT gi.id AS id,
       COUNT(c.id) AS ContadorContenedores, 
       SUM( c.estatus = 1 )  AS ContadorDespachos, 
       SUM( c.estatus = 2 )  AS ContadorCompletado, 
       SUM( c.desconsolidacion = 1 )  AS DesconsolidacionPuerto,
       SUM(c.bultos)  AS bultos
FROM dbgeneralesImportacion LEFT JOIN
     dbcontenedores c 
     ON c.operacion = gi.id
GROUP BY gi.id;
```

MySQL treats boolean values as numbers in a numeric context, with true being 1 and false being 0.  This makes it easy to count up matching values.

Also, only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Using them for column aliases can lead to hard-to-debug problems.

Comment: But using this way returns null when the field in dbcontenedores is null, if I use the way I did it first it returns 0, it's not possible the best practice but the database is in a external server